# Cannot connect iPhone 4 to iMac after Lion upgrade

Tags: iphone, macos, imac

I upgraded my 2009 model iMac to Lion yesterday. I can no longer connect my iPhone in order to synchronize with iTunes. Additionally, if I connect it to the USB port on my wired keyboard, it is also no longer charging the phone. The only way I can charge the phone now is if I use one of the USB ports at the back. Prior to the upgrade I had absolutely no issues using the keyboard USB port for this.

Can anyone offer any hints/tips to assist with troubleshooting this?

Comment: I've just tried with my wires iPhone, and I'm seeing the same behaviour.

Comment: That should read "wifes iPhone". I'm currently investigating a lead where iTunesHelper is not running on the iMac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manually downloaded and re-installed iTunes 10.4 from the Apple website, and this has appeared to have fixed the problem. iTunes is recognizing my iPhone, and I can once again use the USB port on my iMac's keyboard.

Comment: Having the same issue with Macbook and iPhone 4s/iPod Touch 3rd gen.  I will try the full re-install of iTunes when I get home, but I may just do a full reinstall of lion due to issues with Xcode and other programs.  Thanks for posting question and answer!

Comment: No worries. I hope it all goes well for you!